# Fail2Ban Regex - Joomla / PHP5-FPM

Tags: regex, fail2ban

i can't get a regex for fail2ban to work. I want to match the following:

```
[Tue Jun 24 10:22:14.528987 2014] [fcgid:warn] [pid 22526:tid 139757615011584] [client IP:PORT] mod_fcgid: stderr: user admin joomla authentication failure, referer: http://www.mydomain.com/administrator/index.php?option=com_login
```

I tried:

```
^\[.*\s*.*]* \[client <HOST>\] mod_fcgid: stderr: user .* joomla authentication failure, referer: .*
```

Any help would be very appreciated.

Comment: The downvote really sucks because he is really not appropriate.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Just 2 notes:

- In the example we need to use an actual IP and port instead of `IP:PORT`, even if it is fake.
- In the regex you need to catch the IP, and specify the port separately: `<HOST>:[0-9]+`. I assume the port is mandatory.

The test (last line is the regex):

```
fail2ban-regex \
'[Tue Jun 24 10:22:14.528987 2014] [fcgid:warn] [pid 22526:tid 139757615011584] [client 1.2.3.4:1234] mod_fcgid: stderr: user admin joomla authentication failure, referer: http://www.mydomain.com/administrator/index.php?option=com_login' \
'^\[.*]* \[client <HOST>:[0-9]+\] mod_fcgid: stderr: user .* joomla authentication failure, referer: .*'
```

It works for me.

Comment: Thank you so much! That one worked. I totally forgot to regex the port too. Shame on me.

Answer (score 1):

You don't need to have a complex regex to skip over the leading time field. I suspect that's what's causing you problems. For the log entry given this works providing I convert your `IP:PORT`  into a numeric ip:port value.

```
'^.*[[]client <HOST>.*user .*joomla authentication failure,'
```

The above would ban any user with too many authentication failures.

I don't know if you use it but fail2ban-regex is a great tool for this